# ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)

Tags: python-3.x, windows, runtime-error

I was making a virtual assistant in python, but I see the following error.

```
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)
```

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.9

Here is the code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3 
listner=sr.Recognizer()
engine=pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('Hello Vishal. I am Cisco')
engine.say('What do you want me to do?')
engine.runAndWait()
try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice=listner.listen(source)
            command = listner.recognize_google(voice)
            command=command.lower()
            if "cisco" in command:
                 print(command)
except:
    print('Something went wrong')
```

Also when I run this program The console prints this:

```
    enter code hraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\visha\Documents\Python\Basic.py", line 4, in <module>
    engine=pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__       
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__       
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)
PS C:\Users\visha\Documents\Python> ere
```

I am a beginner so I don't have much idea.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 10):

On Command prompt type `python -m site` to get the site-package.
Now navigate to the `site-package` folder and go to `pywin32_system32` to copy `pythoncom39.dll` and `pywintypes39.dll`

Navigate one step back to `site-package` folder and got `win32` and paste the file.

Comment: I needed to add those to two files to win32/lib as well.

Answer (score 7):

try uninstall pywin32 and install it again, works for me

Answer (score 3):

Try importing win32api at the top,

```
import win32api
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
```

Answer (score 2):

You've commented that you dumped the project you were working on.
But I thought I answer anyway for those who still get this error or are going to.

I had the same issue but there was no solution to the problem that I could find online.
So I decided to read the error message and to understand what it says

**Notice that `File <path>` the errors are referring to.**

The `<path>` is `C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\...`.

In this folder, there is a directory called `pywin32_system32`.

That's the directory you're looking for.
The problem was that pypiwin32 was installed but not in the Python PATH that it should have!

For example:

My Python location is `C:\Program Files\Python39`

My Python path in `System Environment Variables` is set to `C:\Program Files\Python39`

When I ran the command `pip install pypiwin32`, it was installed on `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages` which is not the right directory.

Inside the directory, `pywin32_system32`, is the file you are looking for (`pywintypes39.dll`).

**All you have to do is to copy the `pywin32_system32` folder from
`C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\`

to

`<Python_PATH>\site-packages\`**

(`C:\Program Files\Python39\sitepackages\` for example.)

Sorry if the answer came a little too late!
I hope what I wrote is not confusing because I tried my best to explain it in simple words.

Comment: Forgot to write the following: if you still get the same errors from Python external packages that you're sure you've installed, go to Python's AppData folder and copy them to the Python PATH. You may find what you're looking for there.

Comment: You should copy to "C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\site-packages\"

Answer (score 0):

`pywintypes` is a part of Python for Windows extensions, or its know as pywin32 you will need to install it. and i am not sure it will work but you can try this `pip install pypiwin32`.

Comment: Hello Chara98 I tried your method but the Pypiwin32 is already installed. It did not work. Please help if you get a solution.

Comment: oh ok so, can you check if  pywintypes.dll is There in the right path it should be in ```Python38\Lib\site-packages\win32\libs``` or ```Python38\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib``` .

Comment: Also I have checked other places, they asked to copy the dll file from pypiwin32 but this folder is missing from my python directory.

Comment: Thats the issue. I don't have a folder named as win 32 inside the site_packages.

Comment: then you can check in ```Python38\DLLs```

Comment: and which python version do you use?

Comment: I switched from VSCode to Pycharm and the error disappeared. I am using python 3.9

Comment: I am using Python ver-3.8 so i think there is a update in 3.9

Comment: i have dumped that project for now. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Even thou the question is already answered, I had that issue now and used the answer from DecodedIntel, but even thou it works, you can see another issue in the future after using pip install NewModule and there's a way to fix it once and for all.

My Python location is C:\Program Files\Python39

My PIP Modules location is C:\Users<user>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages

To fix it you can use Windows HARD LINK Directory JUNCTION

Use /J to create a hard link pointing to a directory, also known as a directory junction:

mklink /J Link Target

[MSDOS MKLINK Cmd help description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQCXc.png)

So, for example, if you wanted to create a directory junction (a hard link to a folder) at C:\LinkToFolder that pointed to C:\Users\Name\OriginalFolder, you’d run the following command:

mklink /J C:\LinkToFolder C:\Users\Name\OriginalFolder

You’ll need to put quotation marks around paths with spaces. For example, if the folders are instead named C:\Link To Folder and C:\Users\Name\Original Folder, you’d use the following command instead:

mklink /J "C:\Link To Folder" "C:\Users\Name\Original Folder"

If you see the message “You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.”, you need to launch the Command Prompt as Administrator before running the command.

C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\Python>mklink /j Python39 "C:\Program Files\Python39"
Junction created for Python39 <<===>> C:\Program Files\Python39

Answer (score 0):

I did the following when I experienced the same problem:
When we look at these lines in the error,

```
File "C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)
```

The `pywintypes.py` is searching for the `(pywintypes39.dll)` files in the `C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib` directory hence I copied the two files 'pythoncom39.dll' and  'pywintypes39.dll' present in the 'pywin32_system32' folder, to the `C:\Users\visha\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib` directory. It solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\lenevo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib . Just copy  the two files 'pythoncom39.dll' and 'pywintypes39.dll' from the 'pywin32_system32' folder in the lib folder "C:\Users\lenevo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib "