# I am getting error while using pyttsx3 in my program

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-3.9, pyttsx3

I used pyttsx3 for text to speech conversion but it showed an error .I used all required modules including pypiwin32 but even I have uninstall the old version of python which was 2.7 , currently I am using python 3.9 version.

**HERE IS CODE**

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3


listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say('hello I am aura')
engine.say('how may i help you')
engine.runAndWait()
try:
 with sr.Microphone() as source:
     print("listening...")
     voice = listener.listen(source)
     command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
     command = command.lower()
     if 'aura' in command:

         print(command)

except:
 pass
```

**HERE IS ERROR**

```
D:\pycharm\python\python.exe "C:/Users/91931/PycharmProjects/AURA/aura(augmented real assistant).py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "D:\pycharm\python\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91931\PycharmProjects\AURA\aura(augmented real assistant).py", line 6, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "D:\pycharm\python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\91931\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the error I am getting on running my code.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573140/importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes39-dll)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65573140/importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes39-dll)